# Content provider: how to grant permission?

Tags: java, android, permissions

I am trying to grant permission to a other application. But t is dennied what ever i tried? Can somebody help me what to add or change to grant permission for a application within a other package?

Manifest.xml from content provider

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="contentprovider.bob3.nl.bob3admin" >

    <application>
        <provider
            android:name=".BusinessLocationsProvider"
            android:authorities="contentprovider.bob3.nl.provider.Locations"
            android:exported="true"
            android:readPermission="contentprovider.bob3.nl.provider.Locations.permission.READ" />
        <activity>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Manifest.xml from content receiver

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.a42.cat.philips" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="contentprovider.bob3.nl.provider.Locations.permission.READ"/>
    <application>
        <activity android:name=".Intro">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Code that gives exception

```
try{
    Uri allTitles = Uri.parse("content://contentprovider.bob3.nl.provider.Locations/company");
    Cursor c;
        //---Honeycomb and later---
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), allTitles, null, null, null, null);
        c = cursorLoader.loadInBackground()

        String history = "fail";
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do{
                history = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("history"));

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Catch", e.toString());

    }
```

The Exception message from e.toString():

> 12-16 00:04:15.525 885-885/com.a42.cat.philips E/Catch:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
>   contentprovider.bob3.nl.bob3admin.BusinessLocationsProvider uri
>   content://contentprovider.bob3.nl.provider.Locations/company from
>   pid=885, uid=10181 requires
>   contentprovider.bob3.nl.provider.Locations.permission.READ, or
>   grantUriPermission()

The Exception message is from Content provider

> 12-16 00:04:15.500 24290-24328/contentprovider.bob3.nl.bob3admin
>   E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel 12-16 00:04:15.500
>   24290-24328/contentprovider.bob3.nl.bob3admin E/DatabaseUtils:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading
>   contentprovider.bob3.nl.bob3admin.BusinessLocationsProvider uri
>   content://contentprovider.bob3.nl.provider.Locations/company from
>   pid=885, uid=10181 requires
>   contentprovider.bob3.nl.provider.Locations.permission.READ, or
>   grantUriPermission() 12-16 00:04:15.500
>   24290-24328/contentprovider.bob3.nl.bob3admin E/DatabaseUtils:     at
>   android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:467)
>   12-16 00:04:15.500 24290-24328/contentprovider.bob3.nl.bob3admin
>   E/DatabaseUtils:     at
>   android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:394)
>   12-16 00:04:15.500 24290-24328/contentprovider.bob3.nl.bob3admin
>   E/DatabaseUtils:     at
>   android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:194)
>   12-16 00:04:15.500 24290-24328/contentprovider.bob3.nl.bob3admin
>   E/DatabaseUtils:     at
>   android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
>   12-16 00:04:15.500 24290-24328/contentprovider.bob3.nl.bob3admin
>   E/DatabaseUtils:     at
>   android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404) 12-16 00:04:15.500
>   24290-24328/contentprovider.bob3.nl.bob3admin E/DatabaseUtils:     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

Comment: There is no `contentprovider.bob3.nl.provider.Locations.permission.READ` permission in Android. You need to have a `<permission>` element defining that custom permission in the provider's manifest file, and you need the provider app to *always* be installed before the client app.

Comment: So android:readPermission="contentprovider.bob3.nl.provider.Locations.permission.READ"  is not giving the permission? Can you please help me how and where I need to add the <permission>?

Comment: "So android:readPermission="..." is not giving the permission?" -- `android:readPermission` *requires* a permission. The `<uses-permission>` element *requests* a permission. But, since the permission does not exist, the `<uses-permission>` element cannot work. The `<permission>` element is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html). Also, custom permissions [do not work well IMHO](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/PERMS.md).